# Maven and SHA-256

Tags: chef-infra, maven-3, sha

Is there a moderately *painless* way of generating `SHA-256` of `maven` generated artifacts?

I have tried [this plugin](https://checksum-maven-plugin.nicoulaj.net/plugin-info.html) but I cannot make it work. The project builds but there is not `SHA-256` deployed neither in my local repository nor our `nexus` server.

Without `SHA-256` I will not be able to automate the artifact deployment with `Chef` in our nodes. Is there also a *painless* way of avoiding `remote_file` re-download in chef using `SHA1` or `MD5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SHA256 isn't probably what you want anyway, remote_file uses the MD5 for an ETag and sends the last modified time so if Maven implements either of those conditional request type, you should be fine automatically.

Comment: So I should just skip the `checksum` attribute for `remote_file` then? Because (as expected) it does not work with the `MD5` value there.

Comment: Correct, you almost never need an explicit checksum, but make sure Maven supports conditional requests.